# Possible bug with contact detection, values change between collision1 and collision2

Tags: contact

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi,

I am using Gazebo 1.8.0 (but also experienced this behavior with older Gazebo versions). I am subscribing to a contact sensor topic, and just printing out the contacts collision1 and collision2 names.
However in some cases these values change between them.

For example in case of a collision with a table or the ground floor:

```
collision1 = robot hand
collision2 = table / ground floor
```

In case of the objects on the table (spatula, mug, oven):

```
collision1 = the objects
collision2 = robot hand
```

Here is the callback function:

```
void Plugin::OnContact(ConstContactsPtr &_msg)
{
    if(_msg->contact_size() > 0)
    {
    std::cout << "collision1: " << _msg->contact(_msg->contact_size()-1).collision1().c_str() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "collision2: " << _msg->contact(_msg->contact_size()-1).collision2().c_str() << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Here is an output example:

```
collision1: pancake_maker::pancake_maker_link::pancake_maker_collision
collision2: hit_hand::right_hand_thumb_distal_link::right_hand_thumb_distal_link_geom
collision1: hit_hand::right_hand_thumb_distal_link::right_hand_thumb_distal_link_geom
collision2: ias_kitchen::kitchen_link::kitchen_link_geom_counter_top_island_link
```

Cheers,
Andrei

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/2969/possible-bug-with-contact-detection,-values-change-between-collision1-and-collision2/) by [AndreiHaidu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/87/andreihaidu/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 2108 on 2013-05-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

It's debatable whether it's a bug, but it does make it less convenient to parse contact sensor output. I did this exact thing in [MudPlugin.cc:200](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/src/d18b006ad83d62e0325f279bc909de9a48d2aa79/plugins/MudPlugin.cc?at=default#cl-200). The contact data structures are generated by the physics engine and then passed on by the contact sensor without much parsing to avoid performance hits.

It may be convenient to add a variable to custom contact publishers that indicate which collision is attached to the sensor, since the check is already done in [ContactManager::NewContact](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/src/d18b006ad83d62e0325f279bc909de9a48d2aa79/gazebo/physics/ContactManager.cc?at=default#cl-71). Feel free to create a feature request if you think that would be useful.

---

Originally posted by [scpeters](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/109/scpeters/) with karma: 2861 on 2013-05-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1